# How To Shorten All Links In RSS Feed?

Tags: twitter, rss, wordpress, url-shortener

I have an RSS feed that I am sending to twitter and would like all links shortened (via a service like Bitly) automatically. That includes links in the title. I am not interested in links to the posts themselves.

How can I do this? It does not look like the usual tools enable this (hootsuite, feedburner, twitterfeed) and I have tried most WP plugins, but none solve the problem.

Suggestions? Tips? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried the Socialize option with the Publicize tab of FeedBurner? What didn't work?

[TwitterFeed](http://twitterfeed.com/), [dlvr.it](http://support.delivr.com/home) and [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/connect/feed/twitter) are also good [alternatives](http://www.labnol.org/internet/publish-rss-feed-to-twitter/20972/)